# Trouble Connect Query Router to Config Server in MongoDB Sharding

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, azure, sharding

I'm working on my project to Create a Sharded Cluster in MongoDB using Microsoft Azure Ubuntu 14.01 Virtual Machine.

I'm using 3 config server, 2 query router, and 4 shard server.

I already install MongoDB on all those server with version 2.6.9. Then i set up all of the configs server and they worked, they're listening. But when i started to configure the query router instances, it didn't want to connect to the configs server. Here is the command that i use:

```
mongos --configdb config0.example.com:27019,config1.example.com:27019,config2.example.com:27019
```

Here is one of the error message that appear after i run the command.

**Couldn't check dbhash on config server [hostname]:27019 :: caused by :: 11002 socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [[hostname]:27019] connection pool error: couldn't connect to server [hostname]:27019 (23.97.57.219), connection attempt failed.**

Is there any solution of this problem? Really appreciate your help.